# norms of Hilbert space operators

Tags: functional-analysis, proof-explanation

Let $A$ be a bounded linear operator on a complex Hilbert space $V$.

It is well known that 
$$\lVert A\rVert=\sup\left\{ \frac{\lVert Av\rVert}{\lVert v\rVert}\;\colon\; v\in V\text{ with }v\neq 0\right\}.$$

> I want to understand why 
>    $$\begin{align*}
> I &= \inf\{ c\;\colon\; \lVert Av\rVert\leq c\lVert v\rVert \text{ for all }v\in V\}\\
> &=\sup\left\{ \frac{\lVert Av\rVert}{\lVert v\rVert}\;\colon\; v\in V\text{ with }v\neq 0\right\}.
> \end{align*}$$

**Proof:**
Now note that by definition of $\|A\|$ we have
$$ \|Av\| \le \|A\| \|v\| \quad \forall v \in V.$$
 Then $I \le \|A\|$.

On the other hand by definition of $\sup$ we have
$$ I \ge \|Av_n\| /\|v_n\| \ge \|A\| - 1/n \quad \forall n.$$
Then $\|A\| = I$.

> I don't understand why 
>   $$I \ge \|Av_n\| /\|v_n\|?$$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$I+\frac 1 n> c_n$ for some $c_n$ with  $\|Av\| \leq c_n\|v\|$ for all $v$. Hence $I+\frac 1 n> \frac {\|Av\|} {\|v\|}$. Since this is true for all $v \neq 0$ we get $I+\frac 1 n>\sup \{ \frac {{\|Av\|}} {{\|v\|}}: v \neq 0\}$. Now let $n \to \infty$.